# Restrict f:validator on a specific submit button alone

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I'm having a JSF form in which I have a textarea and multiple buttons.
For the text area I'm doing validation using f:validator

```
<f:validator validatorId="myValidator" />
<a4j:support event="onsubmit" ajaxSingle="true" process="textarea1" />
```

The validator is working as expected. Now i have multiple submit buttons on the page i want the validation to happen on specific button only and validator should be ignored on the remaining buttons.

Is there anyway to restrict the validator on a specific submit button alone. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `disabled` attribute.

```
<f:validator validatorId="myValidator" disabled="#{empty param['formId:buttonId']}" />
```

Where `formId` is the ID of your `<h:form>` and the `buttonId` is the ID of the button which is supposed to be the only button to trigger validation.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to submit the `textarea` value to the server when clicking on other buttons too (so no point of playing with the `process` attribute)

How about adding `immediate="true"` to the other buttons ?

That way they will skip validation, while the submit button without `immediate="true"` will do the validation as expected

Or

There seems another workaround in this article [JSF 2 - Conditionally Skip Validation](http://javalabor.blogspot.co.il/2012/02/jsf-2-conditional-validation.html)

Something like

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.someMethod"} value="Submit2">
   <f:param name="skipValidation" value="true"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

and inside the `validate` method of the validator check for the `skipValidation` attirbute (look for further explanation in the article...)